# Switch sound output between internal speakers and external on iMac

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, audio

i have receiver, connected to sound output of my iMac MB950LL/A.

I cannot switch sound to iMac's internal speakers without unplugging the cable from it.

Can it ever be done without touching the cable ?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Yes, see the Output panel in the [System Preferences > Sound](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2490) preference pane.</strike>

Apologies, I did some searching and that iMac model may have the sound output on a hard switch. Annoying. Look for an application called "Audio MIDI Setup" in the Application:Utilities folder and see if that works.

If not, another solution would be to get a USB sound interface, like a [Griffin iMic](http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/imic). Some googling may find a more inexpensive interface. Like maybe [this one](http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=HE-280B&cat=SND).

Comment: No. I cannot do it, because i see only ONE item in the outputs list:
"Internal output", while cable is unplugged; and "External output", while cable is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

The free app [Soundsource](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) puts audio input/output switching on your menu bar.

Comment: It does not work for me. It shows only one output.